# How to print and send changing IDs though python to another computer with sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Basically, I have my code, which finds the Lobby ID of a video-game, which then sends to my laptop. This then opens the exe with a argument and that certain Lobby ID. I want it to change when I start up another game/server. I have the script to output when the lobby ID changes, but when I plug it into my socket script. It only outputs the first one.

If I hash out all the s= socket... part and under it functions correctly

```
import socket
import glob
import os
import re
placeholder = ''

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = '192.168.0.17'
port = 50502
s.connect((host,port))

while True:

    GAME_DIRECTORY = 'C:/Program Files/Oculus/Software/Software/ready-at-dawn-echo-arena'

    logs = glob.glob(GAME_DIRECTORY + '/_local/r14logs/*')
    log = max(logs, key = os.path.getctime)
    with open(log, 'r') as f:
        file = f.read()

    lobbyid = re.findall(r'........-....-....-....-............', file)[-1]
    if lobbyid != placeholder:
        if lobbyid != ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'): 
            placeholder = lobbyid  
            print (lobbyid)

            def ts(str):
                s.send(lobbyid.encode()) 
                data = ''
                data = s.recv(1024).decode()
                s.close ()
            ts(s)
```

Comment: You have a `while True` loop containing just `ts(s)`, so that loop will run forever and your outer loop will not continue;

Comment: Yeh, but if I remove that loop, the ID doesn't get sent to my server script

Comment: How many times do you have to send it? Does it have to be in a loop?

Comment: Depends, all it does is goes into a spectator mode of the current public game/match I am playing in a video-game. So I want to automate it. A new game will be like every 10mins or so

Comment: `    def ts(str):
      s.send(lobbyid.encode()) 
      data = ''
      data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    ts(s)
    s.close ()`

I just tested this, and the same thing happens

Comment: Is the `while True` loop still there? As long as you are doing `while True` there, that little loop will never end.

Comment: No, I removed the while True loop

Comment: See the updated code in the question

Comment: It looks like your line `if lobbyid != placeholder:` is intended to prevent repeatedly printing the same `lobbyid`. But your socket code is outside those `if` statements, so it will keep sending the same `lobbyid` on every execution of the loop (even when it does not print the `lobbyid`). Is that your intention? Should the socket code be indented to place it inside the `if` statements?

Comment: oh right, it already is. That is just stackover flow formating error. Will update now

Comment: Updated, had to copy to a pastebin as formatting errors

Comment: Can't see anything wrong at this point. However, you have a very awkward construction. The `def ts(str)` is bad because `str` is a built-in function, and you are not using that argument anyway. And when you call it with `ts(s)` you are passing the socket as an argument in the `str` position. I would recommend that rather than defining a method and then calling that method, just remove the `def ts(str):` and remove the `ts(s)`, and unindent the contents of the the `ts` method to make it even with `print` statement above it. Doubt that will fix anything, but it makes code easier to understand.

Comment: Also, your socket will get closed after the first `send`.

Comment: Thanks for that. i edited the code, but still the same issue. Could you explain more on the socket closing point?

Comment: You are calling `s.close()`, which closes the socket.